# Behaviour when incrementing a Java long past the maximum

Tags: java

Consider:

```
long n = Long.MAX_VALUE;
++n;
```

With my JVM, this wraps round to `Long.MIN_VALUE`. Is this the *defined* behaviour? Will some JVMs throw an exception instead?

Comment: Yes, this is expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the JLS:

> If an integer addition overflows, then the result is the low-order bits of the mathematical sum as represented in some sufficiently large two's-complement format. If overflow occurs, then the sign of the result is not the same as the sign of the mathematical sum of the two operand values.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2

Answer (score 2):

```
Long.MAX_VALUE 9223372036854775807 = +(2^63-1) : 

01111111.11111111.11111111.11111111.11111111.11111111.11111111.11111111
```

++n will increment this binary number and so the sign bit will be used:

```
Long.MIN_VALUE -9223372036854775808 = -(2^63) : 

10000000.00000000.00000000.00000000.00000000.00000000.00000000.00000000
```

thats not the behaviour of the jvm, thats the behaviour of an icrementation of an binary number.

Answer (score 1):

### It is expected : integer types overflow and underflow silently

[JLS: Primitive Types and Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2) quotes that

> The integer operators do not indicate overflow or underflow in any
>   way.

So as the arithmetic types in Java are signed, adding 1 to `Long.MAX_VALUE` causes overflow and it goes to `Long.MIN_VALUE` as Java uses 2's complement

As the JLS quotes all the integer operators such as `++` will silently overflow the value and not cause any exception

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2) :

> The integer operators do not indicate overflow or underflow in any
>   way.
>
> An integer operator can throw an exception (§11) for the following
>   reasons:
>
> Any integer operator can throw a NullPointerException if unboxing
>   conversion (§5.1.8) of a null reference is required.
>
> The integer divide operator / (§15.17.2) and the integer remainder
>   operator % (§15.17.3) can throw an ArithmeticException if the
>   right-hand operand is zero.
>
> The increment and decrement operators ++ (§15.14.2, §15.15.1) and --
>   (§15.14.3, §15.15.2) can throw an OutOfMemoryError if boxing
>   conversion (§5.1.7) is required and there is not sufficient memory
>   available to perform the conversion.

and [addition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2)(as pointed out by [Svetelin Zarev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2588800/svetlin-zarev)):

> > If an integer addition overflows, then the result is the low-order
> >     bits of the mathematical sum as represented in some sufficiently large
> >     two's-complement format. If overflow occurs, then the sign of the
> >     result is not the same as the sign of the mathematical sum of the two
> >     operand values.

I think it is safe to assume that no exception will be thrown in this case and everytime it will overflow to `Long.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: does not answer the question. OP asks why `MAX_VALUE+1 = MIN_VALUE` and will some JVMs throw exceptions instead. It's not about auto(un)boxing or `%` operator , etc.